# GCP API Gateway / yaml / security definition not working properly

Tags: api, rest, security, google-cloud-platform, yaml

Below is the yaml I used as the config file for a gateway in GCP API Gateway.   They short version is it is ignoring the security definitions.  I can invoke the API with no security/header information and it works find.   I've tried a couple of different tools to make sure there wasn't a cached variable somewhere.

```yaml
`# openapi2-functions.yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Title API
  description: Front end the an API
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /whocantell:
    post:
      summary: mMy API
      operationId: dl
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://someone.somewhere.whoknows
      security:
        - api_key: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "header"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With API Gateway (like with Cloud Endpoint ESPv2 because API Gateway is a managed version of it). Why I'm saying this? Because the constraint and limitation are, most of the time, the same.

If you have a look to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#api_key_definition_limitations), you can find, lost in it, that if you want to add your security key in the header, you need to name it `x-api-key`

Answer (score 0):

As per [Swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters), header parameters named Accept, Content-Type and Authorization are not allowed. To describe the Authorization header, the documentation states to use the corresponding OpenAPI keywords: `securitySchemes, security`

Check this [site](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) for more information about securitySchemes